# UIRefreshControl hidden / obscured by my UINavigationController's UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I'm attempting to use a `UIRefreshControl` inside my `UITableViewController` which itself is inside a `UINavigationController`, which has its `hidesNavigationBar` property set to `NO` (so the navigation bar is visible).

The `UIRefreshControl` works, but is obscured by the `UINavigationBar`. I'm surprised I can't find anyone else who has run into this problem.

Possible relevant points:

- I set the `rootViewController` of my `UIWindow` to be my `UINavigationController`.
- I set the initial view controller of the `UINavigationController` by setting the `viewControllers` property of the `UINavigationController`.
- My `UITableViewController` subclass is instantiated with a nib.
- I instantiate my `UIRefreshControl` in the `viewDidLoad` method of my `UITableViewController` subclass. I set the `refreshControl` property of the `UITableViewController` subclass in this method.
- The `UIRefreshControl` works perfectly fine, and I can see a portion of it, but it is obscured by my `UINavigationBar`. It looks completely normal if I set `hidesNavigationBar` to `YES` (but I don't want to hide it).

## Edit:

The code used to create and position my `UIRefreshControl` is:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(toggleRefresh:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

This code snippet is in the `viewDidLoad` method of my `UITableViewController` subclass, which is a child view controller of a `UINavigationViewController`.

Comment: Try setting the refresh control in viewWillAppear.

Comment: good thought, but doesn't work.

Comment: Then try setting the refresh control in the nib. In the Attributes Inspector, under Table View Controller, you can enable Refreshing.

Comment: Strangely, the Attributes Inspector says "Not Applicable" when I have selected the File's Owner. The class of the File's Owner is a subclass of `UITableView`. Regardless, I don't think it matters whether it is set in the nib or programmatically. I see the `UIRefreshControl`, it just isn't positioned properly.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create and position your Control?

Comment: @VinceBurn I added the code snippet.

Comment: how do you add it to your view?

Comment: Setting the `refreshControl` property of the `UITableViewController` handles everything; the `UITableViewController` manages layout, etc., which is why I'm so perplexed it gets it wrong with a `UINavigationController`. See the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html): "The table view controller handles the work of adding the control to the table’s visual appearance and managing the display of that control in response to appropriate user gestures".

Comment: I've made a test program and was not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @VinceBurn I appreciate your help. There must be something strange going on in my project. Hopefully I'll figure it out eventually. For the moment, I went another route that didn't require a solution to this problem. If I later figure it out I'll post an answer.

Comment: I can easily reproduce your problem with a translucent navigation bar. Everything works just fine if the navigation bar is opaque.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For those targeting iOS 7, there seems to be a new issue present where the `UIRefreshControl` is drawn behind the `UITableView`'s `backgroundView`. I experienced this both when initializing the `UIRefreshControl` programatically and from a storyboard. A simple workaround is to update the `zPosition` of the `UIRefreshControl` in `viewDidLoad` of your `UITableViewController`:

```
self.refreshControl.layer.zPosition = self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I have a table view with a background view (an image) added and I have spent hours trying to work out why the refresh control wasn't showing!

Comment: Thanks but the problem is now that the control is over the table. I tried self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition =self.refreshControl.layer.zPosition- 1; but no success.

Comment: @Ricardo I believe that is expected behavior in iOS 7. You will have to change the table view's offset to show the scroll indicator while it's animating.

Comment: Thanks. I found out myself that it was covered from view by the background image but did not find an easy way of bringing it to front.

Comment: If you'd rather not muck around with the layer's zPosition, you can also work around this by making sure that you initialise the refreshControl *after* setting the tableView's backgroundView.

Comment: @BartVandendriessche It does not work for me, I even tried to do that in `-viewDidApear` last line with no success.

Comment: On iOS 10 this workaround is no longer needed. On iOS 9 the problem still occurs but this workaround solves it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug to me, because it only occures when the contentOffset property of the tableView is 0

see this question

[UIRefreshControl not showing spiny when calling beginRefreshing and contentOffset is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120797/uirefreshcontrol-not-showing-spiny-when-calling-beginrefreshing-and-contentoffse)

I fixed that with the following code (method for the UITableViewController) :

```
- (void)beginRefreshingTableView {

    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(void){

            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

I've find a real solution, here it is:

I've a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` with a translucent `NavigationBar`. Inside the `UIViewController` there is the `UITableView`.

I want to add a `UIRefreshControl` but when I do it, it's hidden by the `NavigationBar`, like you explain.

Here is my code to make it work:

```
// Add a UITableViewController
self.tblViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

// Set the UITableView to it
self.tblViewController.tableView = self.tblView;

// Initialize the UIRefreshControl and set it's method
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Set the RefreshControl to the UITableViewController
self.tblViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;

// Here is the thing ! Just change the contentInset to push down the UITableView content to 64 pixels (StatusBar + NavigationBar)
self.tblView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

With this code, your `UITableViewController` will show the `RefreshControl` perfectly and keep the translucent `NavigationBar` effect when you scroll down the cells.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, self.view is under the navigationBar, except that you write something as follows,

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; // or UIRectEdgeAll & ~UIRectEdgeTop
```

or

```
self.navigationViewController.navigationbar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Jonathan's answer I got this working well. But since I am using storyboard I set the content inset there like so: Which in case someones needs:

[image]
(xcode 6.4)

Answer (score -1):

Do not call `-setTranslucent:` on your `UINavigationBar`. Then, your refresh control will be positioned properly, below the navigation bar.