# UIRefreshControl not showing spiny when calling beginRefreshing and contentOffset is 0

Tags: ios6, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

**I am not able to see the loading spinner when calling `beginRefreshing`**

```
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

My UITableViewController subclass uses a UIRefreshControl

```
// refresh
    UIRefreshControl * refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

It is working perfectly with user interaction (when the user drops the table down), then the spinner is visible.

But when i call `beginRefreshing` on viewDidLoad, I don't see the spinner (only when i drag the table down).

Notes:

- self.refreshControl reference is right
- reloadData or endRefreshing is not called immediately after beginRefreshing, but there is a long time delay (loading data through network), so I am not canceling the beginRefreshing.

Edit :
**This only happens when the `contentOffset` property of the `tableView` is 0 and i call `[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing]`. Bug? Feauture?**

Comment: Where is the duplicate question?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, because it only occures when the `contentOffset` property of the `tableView` is `0`

I fixed that with the following code (method for the UITableViewController) :

```
- (void)beginRefreshingTableView {

    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(void){

            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I get this issue on some of my UITableViews and not the others...

Comment: If your tableview is under a navigation bar, the `offset` will not be `0` but `-self.topLayoutGuide.length`.

Comment: After struggling for whole long day, finally your solution worked

Answer (score 3):

Your fix looks good, But I don't think this as a bug.

When beginRefreshing method is called manually,

When there is no row / cell available it makes sense for refresh control appearing automatically. 
  But when there are some cells available, and when we call begin refresh manually (A scenario where we refresh periodically based on timer) then It should not animate / change the content offset as it will distract the user if he is seeing / reading content in some visible cell.

Comment: I tried calling `-beginRefreshing` when I set number of sections and rows to 0. It still doesn't show the refresh control. If I remembered correctly, it used to work on iOS 6. So it may be a bug.

Comment: swift4: `self.uiRefresh?.beginRefreshing()
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
                self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(self.uiRefresh?.frame.size.height ?? 0))

            }, completion: nil)`